# Could Jenkins dispatch/schedule Build to Build Executor based on the Node CPU utilization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, cpu

I'm running jobs on Jenkins. Jenkins is using AWS EC2 as the Build executor, through Jenkins Plugin Amazon EC2 (https://plugins.jenkins.io/ec2/).

The EC2 type we are using has 16 CPUs, so we could run several builds parallelly in a single EC2. The problem is how to dispatch/schedule these builds?

1. There is a setting in Jenkins Plugin Amazon EC2, `Number of Executors`, which could limit the max concurrent builds running in that EC2. But it's difficult to decide that value. The Jenkins jobs/builds are in various types. Sometimes it only spent 0.5 ~ 1 CPU, but sometimes it spent 8+ CPU for a single run.
2. Is it possible to dispatch the builds by the current EC2 CPU utilization? E.g. we set a CPU utilization throttle as 70%, then when Jenkins is dispatching the new build, it will skip those EC2 with CPU utiliztion above 70%, and only run that new build in a low CPU usage EC2? Is there any Jenkins configuration or Jenkins plugin could achieve this?

Comment: Investigate [Scoring Load Balancer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scoring-load-balancer/) or [Least Load](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/) plugins

Comment: thanks @lanw I just take a quick look at your links. The first one is scheduling the builds by manually scoring the working agents, while the second one is trying to assign the build to an idle one.
But in our situation, there is no `idle` working agent. We say each agent has 10 executor slots, and in anytime 4~6 of them are in use. I just want to assign the new build to the `least CPU utilization` agent. It seems either of the above plugins would work in this way.

Comment: You said "either "; meant "neither "? Least load says : "The least load is defined as a node that is idle or the one with the **most available executors**.", so it's not CPU, rather executor, which is usually 1 executor:1 core (not CPU), unless your jobs forks / parallels. You can also look at extending "Scoring Load Balancer" via extension point. Not aware of any other options.

Comment: thanks @lanw. yes, "neither" works. And for your last comments, you are right. Our problem is that the job runs parallels. There are many kinds of jobs, and each job requires different compute resources, varies from 1 CPU to 8 CPU. So `idle` or `existing executor` is not a good scheduling strategy for us.